# Time Machine - How does one convert Backups.backupdb to a backupbundle?

Tags: backup, time-machine, catalina

I recently had a critical drive failure on my network drive that I use for Time Machine backups. Creating the first backup over the network (with ~1TB of data) will be painfully slow.

I've already created a backup using Time Machine on the drive mounted via USB, however this is a `Backups.backupdb` folder structure, not a `backupbundle` disk image that Time Machine uses when working over the network.

Is there a way to create/convert a new `backupbundle` file with the `Backups.backupdb` folder such that I don't have to run a first full backup over the network? Alternatively, is there a way to convince Time Machine to use the `backupbundle` structure when backing up over USB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I haven't tried this personally, I recently came across a [workaround posted on the MacRumors forums](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/converting-backups-backupdb-to-sparsebundle.2128263/?post=26264622#post-26264622) that claims it should work:

> There is a work around to do this. Attach the drive to the router
> (assuming it supports Time Machine) then start a backup to the disk
> using Time Machine. Give it a couple minutes to get started, then stop
> it and disconnect.
>
> Now attach the drive to the Mac over USB. Look in Finder and you will
> see a sparse bundle with the partial `Backups.backupdb` file there. Just
> delete that file and empty the trash.
>
> Now turn on Time Machine and do a full backup. When it is done you
> will have the full `Backups.backupdb` on the drive. Just move that from
> the root of the drive into the sparse bundle. Now connect it back to
> the router and turn TM back on. It will pick up where it left off with
> incremental backups going forward.

[Another variation on this method](https://superuser.com/questions/904793/time-machine-on-a-local-drive-then-make-that-drive-a-network-drive-via-server) creates a local Samba file share mount on the USB drive as a workaround. Full details in the linked answer, but a summary snippet follows:

> `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2/32`
>
> Plug your usb drive, then via System Preferences / Sharing add a smb share to a folder time-machine-macbook in the drive time-machine-usb Then, add a destination backup (Time Machine will see it as a network share)
>
> `sudo tmutil setdestination -a "smb://user:password@127.0.0.2/time-machine-macbook"`

If there is a simpler/more direct way to do it though, that would be awesome to know! I was thinking maybe something in the `tmutil` command line program may be able to do it, but haven't yet tried.

According to Apple's Disk Utility User Guide, it [appears possible to manually create a sparsebundle disk image](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/disk-utility/dskutl11888/mac):

> - In the **Disk Utility** app  on your Mac, choose **File > New Image > Blank Image**
> - Enter a filename for the disk image, add tags if necessary, then
>   choose where to save it.
> - In the Name field, enter the name for the disk image.
> - In the Size field, enter a size for the disk image.
> - Click the Format pop-up menu, then choose the format for the disk:
>
>   - I believe for Time Machine you will need to choose **Mac OS Extended (Journaled) or Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)** ([reference](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202784#format))
> - To encrypt the disk image, click the Encryption pop-up menu, then
>   choose an encryption option.
> - Click the Partitions pop-up menu, then choose a partition layout.
> - Click the Image Format pop-up menu, then choose an option:
>
>   - **Sparse bundle disk image:** Same as a sparse disk image (below), but the
>     directory data for the image is stored differently. Uses the
>     `.sparsebundle` file extension.
>   - **Sparse disk image:** Creates an expandable file that shrinks and grows
>     as needed. No additional space is used. Uses the `.sparseimage` file
>     extension.
> - Click Save, then click Done.
> - Disk Utility creates the disk image file where you saved it in the
>   Finder and mounts its disk icon on your desktop and in the Finder
>   sidebar.
> - In the Finder, copy your files to the mounted disk image, then eject
>   it.

**Edit Note:** macOS Catalina appears to use the extension `backupbundle` instead of `sparsebundle`, but it seems that this file is still mountable in the same ways as previously.

Comment: Thanks @glenn-devalias! I tried what you suggested. Unfortunately lots of things got in my way:  
  
1. Time Machine over the network creates a `backupbundle` file, at least for me. Maybe it's a Catalina thing? I don't know...  
2. The `backupbundle` file it is not mountable (at least I could find no way to do it).  
3. The file structure of the `backupbundle` is very different than I expected, and did not contain a `Backups.backupdb` folder.  
  
At this point 835GB of the 940GB for the initial backup has been completed... Sometimes brute force is the way to go... ;-)

Comment: It does sound like it is a Catalina thing, according to: https://www.macworld.com/article/3445481/can-t-find-your-time-machine-backup-after-upgrading-to-catalina-look-for-a-backupbundle.html I haven't tried it, but it suggests that you may be able to rename the `backupbundle` back to a `sparsebundle`, then mount it that way. If that's the case, you could probably also pass the `backupbundle` directly to a command line command to mount it as a `sparsebundle`. I haven't tried either of these yet, as all my backups appear to predate Catalina.

Comment: There is another article at https://eclecticlight.co/2019/11/11/time-machine-and-backing-up-in-catalina/ that talks about this, and suggests "that the new `backupbundle` can still be mounted using an older `DiskImageMounter` app in `/System/Library/CoreServices`, although whether you can use Time Machine to retrieve any of its contents remains unclear"

Comment: Thanks @glenn, appreciate your efforts. Ultimately I was unable to convert the `Backups.backupdb` to a `backupbundle`, even thought it doesn't seem like it should be that complicated. So backup history began anew, which isn't entirely bad.

Comment: I wanted a setup with a large hard drive plugged into my Mac, then that Mac using it for Time Machine backup and another Mac doing the same over the network. No chance.